# Bashrc issue WSL version 2

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been working on a Bash script. Its an existing script that basically installs component.

Now we have functions and these functions are called at the bottom of the script so for instance.

So I'm using WSL ubuntu 20.04 and version 2

```
#!/bin/bash 

installTerraform()
{
    if [ "$(terraform --version | grep -c "$TF_LATEST_VERSION")" -eq 0 ]; then
       
        printf "Downloading tfswitch and Terraform ${TF_LATEST_VERSION}..."

        DOWNLOAD_URI="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/warrensbox/terraform-switcher/release/install.sh"

        if ! (tfswitch -v > /dev/null); then
            printf "Installing tfswitch first..."
            curl -L "$DOWNLOAD_URI" > ~/install_tfswitch.sh
            source ~/install_tfswitch.sh -b ~/bin
            rm -f ~/install_tfswitch.sh
        fi
        source ~/.bashrc
        tfswitch -b "$TFSWITCH_INSTALL_LOCATION/terraform" "$TF_LATEST_VERSION"

        printf "$("$TFSWITCH_INSTALL_LOCATION/terraform" --version | head -n 1) installed $TICK"
    else
        printf "$TICK Terraform $TF_LATEST_VERSION already installed"            
    fi
   
}
```

But what I'm finding is that bashrc is failing to run from my script. So it gets to the end of the script tries to launch say tfswitch command not found.

tfswitch: command not found

Run source ~/.bashrc then launch tfswitch again and it runs.

What am I missing? cheers in advanced.

```
===============================================./buildmachine.sh: line 248: terraform: command not found
Downloading tfswitch and Terraform 1.4.5..../buildmachine.sh: line 254: tfswitch: command not found
Installing tfswitch first...  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  9272  100  9272    0     0  43125      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 43125
warrensbox/terraform-switcher info checking GitHub for latest tag
warrensbox/terraform-switcher info found version: 0.13.1308 for 0.13.1308/linux/amd64
warrensbox/terraform-switcher info installed /home/weasle/bin/tfswitch
./buildmachine.sh: line 261: tfswitch: command not found
weasle@IIS-LP-64:/mnt/c/repo/bashscripts$ tfswitch
tfswitch: command not found
weasle@IIS-LP-64:/mnt/c/repo/bashscripts$ source ~/.bashrc
weasle@IIS-LP-64:/mnt/c/repo/bashscripts$ tfswitch
Creating directory for terraform binary at: /home/weasle/.terraform.versions
Use the arrow keys to navigate: ↓ ↑ → ←
? Select Terraform version:
  ▸ 1.5.2
    1.5.1
    1.5.0
    1.4.6
↓   1.4.5
```

Comment: If I were to guess -- is `tfswitch` an alias? Aliases are an interactive-only feature; they don't work in scripts. But you shouldn't be writing scripts that use or rely on .bashrc in the first place -- it's explicitly for **interactive** shell configuration.

Comment: Of course, it could also be that your `.bashrc` does something like `[[ $- = *i* ]] || return` or `[ -t 0 ] || return` before reaching the parts you need, but since you aren't showing it we have no way to know.

Comment: Hi Charles, Its a weird on there is nothing in the bashrc file pertaining to tfswitch. So im thinking why after install is if saying command not found then after reloading bashrc its goes ohhh yeah i know this command.

Comment: Sourcing a file doesn't "reload" it -- it executes each line, but it doesn't have any reference to whether the file was previously run, so it doesn't do things like unload/revert changes made by the original version. Anyhow -- what _is_ `tfswitch`? Is it an executable, found through the PATH? An alias? A function?

Comment: Use `type tfswitch` at your interactive shell to answer that. And use `bash -x yourscript` to run the script with tracing enabled; compare the commands that come from your `.bashrc` in that log when the script is sourcing it to the commands you see in `(set -x; . ~/.bashrc)` at an interactive prompt.

Comment: Hi Charles, Tfswitch is used to switch between terraform versions. But I think you already know this. Apologies new to linux and learning so please be gentle. Now i added bash -x to my script and i got an output of ++ did a search for set and nothing? Also looked for PATH and nothing. So im not sure if the issue is WSL or Ubuntu. But I'm going to test the script on a full version of Ubuntu when I get a chance to spin up a VM

Comment: It should be `set -x` if you put it _inside_ the script (be sure you put it before the commands that need to be traced), or `bash -x scriptname` to start the script in xtrace mode from the command line just once. If you mean the `source` command shows the bashrc as containing no commands... Hmm, interesting.

Comment: And since I don't use Terraform (I've done devops for a lot of years but not with that particular stack) I don't know how tfswitch is defined; I'm _guessing_ it's an alias because that would explain your error, but I really do need you to run `type tfswitch` in an interactive shell where tfswitch works to get a definitive answer.

Comment: BTW, one thing you can do to make xtrace output easier to follow is to set a PS4 variable that tells it to print which file and line each command came from. `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO}+'` is a good place to start. Surest way to ensure that's honored is to define it at the top of your script (for security reasons some versions of bash ignore it when inherited through the environment if the current user is root); it'll only do anything when `set -x` is enabled so it's safe to leave in even when you aren't debugging.

Comment: HI Charles, Tfswitch allows you to switch between terraform version. So with TFswitch you can specify what version of terraform you want to use and it downloads it and sets it to that version.  Now what I noticed is the script ran installed Tfswitch and would error with the command above. But if you opened another terminal it ran fine so installing. I also moved source ~/.bashrc into bash_profile sometimes when I launched a new tab it didnt reload bashrc. This got me over the hurdle but not sure why? Would be nice to understand though

Comment: Traditionally: `.bash_profile` is used for _login_ shells, `.bashrc` is used for interactive shells that _aren't_ login shells. It's typical to make `.bash_profile` source `.bashrc` so its contents are available in both cases.

Comment: The idea with a login shell is that it's going to be the parent process of other interactive shells, so you use `.bash_profile` (or more generically `.profile`) to set environment variables, exported functions, and other things you only need to set once per session (like `PATH` changes), as opposed to things you need to set for every individual shell (like prompt configuration, or functions and aliases).

Comment: I did say "traditionally", because some operating systems (particularly MacOS) don't follow thole rules; the details depend on exactly which platform you're on.